# automaticly attach event to all XMLhttprequests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

im trying to find a solution to catch all errors when using ajax (xmlhttprequest) happening because of crosssite. I have tried the obvious with

```
window.onerror = function(msg,url,text) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

but both the 404 error and crosssite warning is not catched by this.

The triggy part is that i cannot attach an errorhandler to the xmlhttprequest when i create it, as it is create multiple places in the code, plus in some 3rd part scripts hosted outside my reach.

So im thinking about a solution where are attach an event (error handler) automaticly whenever an object is created.

Hope this make sense :)

BR/Sune

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? if you are there are global event handlers for ajax -> http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: @ManseUK - Thanks for the answer. I have actually already tried this and it works for all ajax requsts done with jQuery. But i have situations where jquary is not used to do the ajax and they are not catched using ajaxError :(